# whats the best way to crop off decimals php

Tags: php

I'm making a php script, and it does math to find a float.

```
$levels = $userData['xp']/100
```

How can I make it generate $level where the result of $levels is converted into an integer, by removing the decimals (not rounding) so if xp is 99 $levels is 0.99 $level will be 0

Comment: Too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`floor()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.floor.php) your round your value down to the next lower int.

```
<?php
$float = 0.99;
$int = floor($float);
var_dump($int); // prints '0'
```

Comment: Casting floats to integers is not a good idea. A simple sample `(int) (290.15 * 100)` will explain you why.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @user1597430 what about `floor()`?

Comment: floor/ceil/round should be safe, you can also work with integers directly via `%` operator